# Alien invasion story involving satellite trying to build a portal

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I heard this audio book maybe ten-twelve years ago. It was American and voice-acted quite well.

It concerned a satellite being sent to earth by extra-terrestrials. It was intelligent and believed it had the measure of humanity. It proceeded to create a biological weapon designed to force humanity to build a portal device that would allow for an invasion to take planet earth by surprise.

This weapon manifests as a body-snatcher which attaches and burrows deep in the body of the protagonist, it has an outgrowth on the skin and deep roots which it can manipulate making it near impossible to remove, it speaks to our protagonist telepathically and causes terrible pain if it feels disobeyed or threatened. It understands the concept of emergency services and vehemently opposes it.

The protagonist is forced to surgically remove them himself, and one is on his manhood. Obviously the "things" are aware of this procedure and tries to stop him.

He ends up having to dismember himself to rid himself of the alien infection - to stop the voices so to speak. He is found by another character of the story while carrying his own dismembered part to seek medical assistance. He is grinning at this point because he beat them.

His manhood is reattached and he is recruited to fight the invasion.

The protagonist I describe is very big, fairly young, Caucasian and he has serious father-issues.

I also remember a few other disjointed details:

The protagonist bonds with the man who found him after the dismemberment. This man is definitely the recruiter.

The protagonist is beaten half to death by said man with a piece of furniture, for disobedience I think, during this beating the protagonist screams "Please stop hurting me daddy," or something to that effect. This outburst ends the confrontation and serves to bring the two men close together, strengthening their bond.

The satellite was hit by a laser or something but still managed to make a final weapon and hurl it at us before being incinerated.

Aliens nearly succeeded providing a fairly typical conclusion with human victory, but open-ended because the satellite built the aforementioned weapon.

I think I may be describing more than one book, possibly a trilogy.

Comment: Someone cutting off his own dick, subsequently reattached, to foil an alien invasion? Sounds very Piers Anthony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the book [Infected](https://scottsigler.com/book/infected/), by Scott Sigler. Key points:

- Alien infection begins as something like [Morgellon's disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgellons) (red and
- blue fibers in the skin)
- Aliens communicate with/control their host humans, who are compelled to build portals through which the main invasion will commence.
- The dismemberment happens with a pair of kitchen shears.